# Saving checked state when re-using recyclerview

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

I'm wondering what the best way to save the checked state on a recycler view when it is re-used multiple times?

I have a expandable listview with 15 options, each of those 15 options has 5 child items. Each child item when clicked goes to an activity that has 3 fragment tabs. Each tab has it's own recycler view. I have set up the adapter so it knows what fragment it is in, by adding an integer, and when setting the adapter to the recycler view, it saves the checkmarks from tab to tab. (So if im in the first tab, check 3 items, switch tabs, check 2 items, it will save those properly.)

Here is my recycler view adapter where I add the integer:

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

Context mContext;
ArrayList<Workout> workout;
SharedPreferences prefs;
int firstSecondOrThird;
int colorResId = R.color.defaultcard;

public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Workout> workout, int thePosition) {
    mContext = context;
    this.workout = workout;
    this.firstSecondOrThird = thePosition;
}
```

And here is the tab fragment where I set up adapter to recycler view(first tab):

```
//RECYCLERVIEW
    final RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerMon);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));

    rv.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerAdapter(this.getActivity(), getMondayWorkout(), 1));
```

second tab:

```
//        //RECYCLERVIEW
final RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerWed);
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
rv.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerAdapter(this.getActivity(), getWedWorkout(), 2));
```

This works well, unfortunately, when I go back to the exp list view and click a different child item, those checkmarks are still there, since it only saves the tab and not which child item was clicked.

Here is how I save checkmark(in recycler adapter onBindViewHolder):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.exercise.setText(workout.get(position).getExercise());
    holder.percent.setText(workout.get(position).getPercent());
    holder.reps.setText(workout.get(position).getReps());
    holder.weight.setText(workout.get(position).getWeight());
    holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("checkState", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            prefs.edit().putBoolean(firstSecondOrThird + "checkState" + position, isChecked).apply();
        }
    });
    holder.check1.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(firstSecondOrThird+"checkState"+position, false));
}
```

I'm wondering the best way to let the recycler view save the checkbox state for each individual child item. 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

i am not sure this will solve your problem but in my case it work,but i am sure it give you a idea

```
SparseBooleanArray selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
    mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mCheckBox.setChecked(!mCheckBox.isChecked());
            if (selectedItems.get(getAdapterPosition(), false)) {
                selectedItems.delete(getAdapterPosition());
                v.setSelected(false);
            } else {
                selectedItems.put(getAdapterPosition(), true);

                v.setSelected(true);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, is this in onCreateViewHolder or OnBindViewHolder? Would you be able to post the full code for where it is please, thanks

Comment: Sorry for late You can add this code inside on click

Answer (score 0):

Due to complexity of your situation, I would suggest setting the adapter itself as the listener to the clicks, have it save the data, and have it set the value in onBind function. In addition, in onBind function, set a tag to identify each CheckBox, so that adapter could just getTag to know which value was clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing this. I think the adapter is currently handling the onClick events as shown in the onBindViewHolder above, I'm not too sure how I would set a tag for each checkbox either.. would you be able to give an example please :)